# How can I evaluate an array of lambda functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, lambda

I am trying to write a function that will create a list of lambda functions and then passing an array to this list.

I figured out how to hard code this function list, however, I cannot seem to figure out how to use a for loop to create the list.

For example, let's take a very simple function where we multiply every element of A by 1, then 2, then 3, ... and so on so that each row corresponds to the element of A and each column corresponds to the number at which A is multiplied by.

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4])

def f():
    F3 = lambda x: 3*x
    F2 = lambda x: 2*x
    F1 = lambda x: 1*x
    F0 = lambda x: 0*x
    return lambda x: np.stack((F3(x),F2(x),F1(x),F0(x)),axis=1)

F = f()
F(A)
```

My output is then.

```py
array([[ 3,  2,  1,  0],
       [ 6,  4,  2,  0],
       [ 9,  6,  3,  0],
       [12,  8,  4,  0]])
```

The code above only goes to 3*x.  What would I do if I want to follow the pattern to n*x?  My basic idea would be as follows (however, this does not work):

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4])

def _f():
    return lambda x: n*x
def f(N):
    F = []
    for n in range(N):
        F.append(lambda x: _f(n))
    return np.array(F)

F = f(5)
F(A)
```

In real life, my function _f() is far more complicated. The motivation behind this is that I would rather have my program iterate through each _f only once and then perform the calculation F(A) in one shot.

The desired output of can be achieved by the following code, however, this will iterate through the loop each time F is called.

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4])

def _f(n,x):
    return n*x
def f(N,x):
    F = []
    for n in range(N):
        F.append(_f(n,x))
    return np.array(F)

F = f(5,A)
print(F.T)
```

This would return:

```py
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 0  2  4  6  8]
 [ 0  3  6  9 12]
 [ 0  4  8 12 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`_f` (properly defined; it should take `n` as an argument rather than treating `n` as a global variable) is already the function which, when called, returns your desired function.

```
# Or _f = lambda n: lambda x: n * x
def _f(n):
    return lambda x: n * x

F = [_f(n) for n in range(N)]
```

That said, you can avoid lambda expressions and their scoping issues altogether by using `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import mul


F = [partial(mul, n) for n in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop is broken:

```
for n in range(N):
    F.append(lambda x: _f(n))
```

because `n` is lazily read in the body of the function (so all the functions stored read the *final* value of `n` from the loop).

The easiest fix is to bind `n` as a default *argument*; default arguments are bound eagerly at definition time:

```
for n in range(N):
    F.append(lambda x, n=n: _f(n))
                     ^^^^^ Changed part
```

If you want to avoid the default argument, make your factory function do the eager binding for you:

```
def _f(n):  # Now receives n as an argument to outer function
    return lambda x: n*x  # While inner function uses n from closure and x passed when called
```

then use it with:

```
for n in range(N):
    F.append(_f(n))
```

Comment: That solves one part, however, I cannot figure out how to pass my array into my function.  F comes out as a list of functions.  My end goal is to write my function f in such a way that I can pass my array to it and it will perform each function on each element of the array.  The output should be similar to the iterative method that I showed above.

Comment: @Epsilon1024: I assume the answer would be to just convert to a `tuple` and return the necessary function, e.g. `return lambda x: np.stack(tuple(reversed(F)), axis=1)`. Never used `numpy.stack` (what you have doesn't look right to me based on the docs), but I'm not a `numpy` expert; that `return` should be functionally equivalent, but dynamically sized.